# How to filter a domain?

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

Is it possible to segment based on URL path?

Say I have one Google Analytics account with one created property (tied to **abc.com)**. Depending on your login information, it will send you to **abc.com/red**, **abc.com/blue** or **abc.com/yellow.**

Is it possible to create separate views for `/red`, `/blue` and `/yellow`? How do you implement a custom filter for it?

Using Google Data Studio, how would you add a filter control to filter between `/red`, `/blue` and `/yellow`?

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (additionally, a Google Sheet if it's the data set) of the scenario (using sample data that shows 1) Input values (~10 rows) 2) Expected output 3) An attempt at solving the issue)? It would help users visualise the issue and test out suggestions on a specific use case with objective right / wrong answers. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart

Answer (score 0):

In your GA filter for the view choose :

predefined -> include only traffic to the subdirectories -> that are equal to -> /red/